# Unable to solve .htaccess url rewriterule, gives 404 for all pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to show URL like below examples:

1) http://www.domainname.com/detail/name/123.html

2) http://www.domainname.com/detail/124.html

In both URLs I want to show if "name" exist then want to display URL with "name" otherwise without "name".

```
1) RewriteRule ^detail/(.*).html$ detail.php?id=$1 [QSA]
2) RewriteRule ^detail/(.*)/(.*).html$ detail.php?id=$2 [QSA]
```

First rule is working file without "name". Second rule is not working and gives 404 for all pages.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just one rule to handle both cases:

```
RewriteRule ^detail/(?:[^/]+/)?([^./]+)\.html$ detail.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: How come you get `http://www.domainname.com/detail/name/821.htmlhttp://www.domainname.com/detail/name/821.html%22`? My suggested rule is not doing any redirect. Do you have other rules in your htaccess not shown in question?

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, you are having same answer as above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having, is that the first rule matches both your first and second case. Obviously when id is `name/123` your application can't handle it. What you want to do is limiting the characters to non-slash characters. After all, that means it can only match the last path segment. Besides that, force yourself to **always** escape literal dots in a regex. A dot matches pretty much anything if you don't do that...

```
RewriteRule ^detail/([^/]+)\.html$ detail.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^detail/[^/]+/([^/]+)\.html$ detail.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```